# How to automatically change dock position when plugging an external monitor?

Tags: display, dock

When I use the screen of my MacBook Pro, I have the dock at the left.

When I connect my external monitor to my MacBook Pro (configured side by side at the same vertical level) the dock is now on my external monitor on the left. I would like to have the dock at the bottom on my external monitor instead, **without having to do it manually each time**.

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378936/179928) suggests using *ControlPlane* but the app doesn't exist anymore.

Does someone think it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using Apple Script and a combination of previous answers:

- [Detect when a second monitor is attached and trigger a script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333556/how-do-i-trigger-a-script-when-a-second-monitor-is-attached)
- [Move the position of the dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46046/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-the-position-of-the-dock)

It might involve some experimentations to combine things properly but it is totally possible!